# Android specific imageview zoom

Tags: android, android-imageview, zooming

I have an activity with two imageviews one on another(merged in xml). one is an image and the other is a transparent frame. so i wanted to zoom the image alone and not frame. How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a custom class extending imageview solved my problem. Following url has a tutorial that was helpful to me:
 `[http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/][1]`

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for that. You can probably achieve this effect yourself by drawing the text using the 2D graphics APIs (Canvas) and touch events. Or, intercept touch events on a TextView and change the font size of the text.

Comment: Thanks but really did not understand what u exactly mean? i have two image views merged on one another. Whats the textview you r talking about?